# Remove empty elements, that only contain white spaces

Tags: jquery

I want to remove empty `<p></p>` from my page. This works great with `$('p:empty').remove();`. But I also have some `<p>`'s on my page, that look like this (only containing a lot of white spaces):

```
<p>
                                        </p>
```

And unfortunately, they are not recognized as empty.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).remove()
    }
});
```

Comment: what if you have <p><div></div></p> ? This method doesn't work then

Comment: True, but that's not what was requested:)

Comment: @alen Wow, you really know how to be nice to other people :P

Comment: @JohnEllmore Cool.

Comment: I liked the version which used `el` instead of `this`. It was more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Use this method:

1- Get the inner html of it
2- trim it
3-compare it with ""

```
$('p').each(function() {
     var $p = $(this);
     if($.trim($p.html())==='') {
        $p.remove();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx for this. We simply look for anything that starts and ends with spacing with nothing in between(line breaks, spaces, tabs): `^\s+$` and remove the node. We do the same if the node contains nothing`^$`.

```
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
  if ((/^\s+$|^$/gm).test(paragraph.textContent)) paragraph.parentNode.removeChild(paragraph);
});
```

```js
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
  if ((/^\s+$|^$/gm).test(paragraph.textContent)) {
    paragraph.parentNode.removeChild(paragraph);
    console.log(paragraph, "removed");
  }
});
```

```html
<p>

</p>

<p> hola </p>

<p> </p>

<p> </p>

<p> hiya </p>
<p> </p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Creating a new RegEx in each iteration must be much less efficient than just using `.trim()` like in the other solutions. Nice to have a plain JS solution though along with the others.

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost in standard JS it appears that .trim would be faster, but in this current circumstance using JQuery, this pulls out ahead https://jsperf.com/trim-vs-regex-for-replacing-string

Comment: Absolutely, jQuery slows things down. I was more interested in replacing your RegEx with native String.prototype.trim() (since your is the answer optimised for speed). I get mixed results, trim() is faster most of the time in by browser, but not always. https://jsperf.com/native-string-trim-vs-regex